# Python 2.7: How to separate extracted text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 2.7 with Beautiful soup to get some text from an URL, but I want to separate the extracted text in each row.

This is how I extract the text from the URL and put the output in a CSV file:

```
# import libraries
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
url = 'http://www.bkfrem.dk/default.asp?id=19'

# query the website and return the html to the variable â€˜pageâ€™
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# create CSV file
csvfile = csv.writer(open('firsteam.csv', 'w'))
csvfile.writerow(('Name', 'Position', 'Height', 'Weight', 'Born', 'Image'))

# take out the <div> of name and get its value
items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'visTruppenContainer'})

for i in range(len(items)):

    playerInfo = items[i].getText(separator=u' ')
    imageURL = items[1].find('img')['src']
    csvfile.writerow([playerInfo.encode('iso8859-15'), imageURL])
    print (playerInfo)
    print (imageURL)
```

So basically what I get is `('Name', 'Position', 'Height', 'Weight', 'Born')` in one row (same column), and the playerInfo and imageURL in another row (same column). What I am trying to achieve to is to, firstly, separate `('Name', 'Position', 'Height', 'Weight', 'Born')`, so that they get a column each. Next I want to split the data I extract so that they belong to the corresponding column.

This is how the output looks like now:
[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the items you read differently:

```
for i in range(len(items)):

    playerInfo = items[i].getText(separator=u'%').encode('iso8859-15').split('%')
    imageURL = items[1].find('img')['src']
    csvfile.writerow(playerInfo + [imageURL])
    print (playerInfo)
    print (imageURL)
```

Comment: The output is still the same. Different rows, but same columns

Comment: @Bab The proposed solution works. You have to select `comma` as separator when loading the CSV file to LibreOffice Calc or MS Excel.